# Not able to get the exact source for a URL

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to extract a source page of a given URL with a C# application. Right now I am using class `HttpWebRequest`.

The strange thing is that the result page obtained from this class is completely different compared to the page obtained with a Google Chrome browser(Ctrl + u).

Can somebody please tell me how to get the exact source page. Or is it wrong to expect that both pages are equal?

Many thanks

Comment: the user agent is different - that could be a factor. also javascript could manipulate the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Web Browser can be trivial though the html will be properly retrieved from the internet. The code will require you to call another void or place the code within the event.

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    wb.Navigate("http://kissanime.com/Anime/One-Piece");
    wb.ScriptSupress = true;
    wb.DocumentCompleted += pageLoaded;
}

private void pageLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    string src = wb.DocumentText;
}
```

by using that method you will get the html straight out of a web browser though it can take time to load depends on the size of the page, images and dependencies (External files like JS, CSS and Pictures/Videos).

Comment: Your welcome. Just make sure ScriptSupress is enabled or you will get popups about allowing scripts.